# Using APIGEN with Netbeans and Virtualbox

Tags: php, virtualbox, development-environment, netbeans-8, apigen

My dev environment has an ubuntu server 14.04 running inside a VirtualBox. I use Mac OS X where I have Netbeans and other supporting software installed. Only the server component resides in VirtualBox.

```
Mac OS X
|- Netbeans
|- VirtualBox
  |-- Ubuntu Server 14.04 (LAMP)
```

My question is how do I run ApiGen in Netbeans without installing pear/apigen in Mac OS X?

Currently I get the following error,

```
Warning: require(Nette/Diagnostics/Debugger.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/apigen on line 48

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Nette/Diagnostics/Debugger.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/bin/apigen on line 48
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you using PHAR file to avoid conflicts with your version libs (probably composer or other version conflict).

You can download it on homepage https://github.com/apigen/apigen#installation